# Limit of an iterative sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x)$ be the function on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)= \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$. For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the sequence $(x_n(y))$ defined by $x_0(y)=y$ and $x_{n+1}(y)=f(x_n(y))$ for all $n\ge1$ and let $g(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n(y)$. Find $\int_{0}^{3}g(y)dy$

My approach: I had prove that the sequence is contractive sequence, hence Cauchy and hence convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. Between $0\leq y\leq1$, $g(y)$ exist and it is equal to zero.

I am not able to think further

Comment: You can restrict to $y\ge0$ since $g(-y)=-g(y),$ and to $y\le1$ since $g(y)=g(\sin(\pi y/2)).$

Comment: *“Between $0\leq y\leq1$, $g(y)$ exist and it is equal to zero.”* – No, that is not true. I suggest to plot the first iterates $x_1, x_2, x_3$ over the interval $[0, 4]$ to get an idea what the limit function looks like.

Comment: Between 0 to 2 it converges to 1, between 2 to 4 it converges to -1?

Comment: So integration will attain value 1 by assuming all the value of g(x) between 1 and 3. That's it?

Comment: Correct. Now try to *prove* it.